# How to make an action if a line was printed using print?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I’m making a little assistance management on python that prints a message and then writes the assistance data on a file after the message was printed but I can’t make an ‘if print: statement’ code.

I haven’t seen any solution yet, and I’m new to this so I don’t even know how to search it up.

I want to open a file after the message is printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options (given the sketchy description):

- Repeat the logic that decided to print to decide whether or not to write to the file (if possible)
- Have the code that prints the message change a variable (say, `didPrint`) from `False` to `True`, and check that variable to decide whether to not to write to the file.

If you need to know *what* was printed, save that to a variable you can use when writing to the file.